# How to convert the value inside an interface into a map in golang?

Tags: go, response, go-interface

I am a complete newbie to GO.

My objective is to get the data inside item.Data and put them into a map so that I can access them  as a key value pair.

As far as I understand an empty interface is as same as any type in Typescript.

Can you please share a snippet of how to do it  in goLang?

```
type SearchLogsResponse struct {

    // The underlying http response
    RawResponse *http.Response

    // A list of SearchResponse instances
    SearchResponse `presentIn:"body"`

    // For list pagination. When this header appears in the response, additional pages
    // of results remain. For important details about how pagination works, see
    // List Pagination (https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/usingapi.htm#nine).
    OpcNextPage *string `presentIn:"header" name:"opc-next-page"`

    // Unique Oracle-assigned identifier for the request. If you need to contact
    // Oracle about a particular request, please provide the request ID.
    OpcRequestId *string `presentIn:"header" name:"opc-request-id"`
}
```

// SearchResult A log search result entry

```
type SearchResult struct {

    // JSON blob containing the search entry with projected fields.
    Data *interface{} `mandatory:"true" json:"data"`
}


// SearchResponse Search response object.
type SearchResponse struct {
    Summary *SearchResultSummary `mandatory:"true" json:"summary"`

    // List of search results
    Results []SearchResult `mandatory:"false" json:"results"`

    // List of log field schema information.
    Fields []FieldInfo `mandatory:"false" json:"fields"`
}

res, err1 := o.loggingSearchClient.SearchLogs(ctx, request)
    for _, item := range res.Results {

            //TODO create a map string [string]

            // Put key value pairs from item into the above map




}
```

P.S: The data inside item.Data  is a list of key value pair where each key could contain data inside another  interface whose value is a string

Edit : Keys are dynamic

[Github Link](https://github.com/athulmurali/oci-grafana-plugin/blob/test-log-panel/datasource.go#L677)

[image: Screenshot of interface containing data]

Comment: Do you know all the keys inside intem.Data or the list of keys is dynamic?

Comment: Keys are dynamic. Also updating my question

Comment: Show the code. What is item? What is 
Data?

Comment: @BurakSerdar Done

Comment: Sorry, nobody's going to go through a 600 line source file. Add the relevant pieces to your post.

Comment: Sorry, that's ls a link pointing to that particular line  to provide a better context @BurakSerdar

Comment: "I am a complete newbie to GO." Take the Tour of Go and do the exercises. This will be much more helpful for  you in the long run.

Comment: @Volker Will do for sure but I had to do a minor fix that was time bound, hence asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: do not use `*interface{}`, instead use `interface{}`.

You can use type assertions to test the underlying type of `Data` and recursively descend if it is a `map[string]interface{}`:

(You mentioned this is part of the SDK and cannot be changed, so the workaround is to dereference the interface)

```
if m, ok:=(*item.Data).(map[string]interface{}); ok {
   // m is a map[string]interface{}
   etag:=m["data.eTag"]
   // etag is an interface{}
   if str, ok:=etag.(string); ok {
      // str contains the string value
   }
}
```

Comment: First: do not use *interface{}, instead use interface{} 

This cannot be done , because it is part of the sdk that is being imported 

Can you please suggest a work around ?

Comment: Edited the answer to dereference